# Configure router to redirect URL to custom IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing, redirection

I have an Asus AX55 router and a simple ESP32-based device running a web server and connected by WiFi to the router. I made the router to assign it a fixed IP of `192.168.50.82`.

Now, I would like to config the router to redirect some URL, say `mydev` to this IP.
So I would like to type into browser `http://mydev/some/cmd` and I would like the router to redirect it to `http://192.168.50.82/some/cmd`.

**Is it possible to do?**

(Basically, I want what the `hosts` file does on Linux / Windows, but done by the router, not my OS, so it works with mobile phones etc).

Comment: It’s important to note that this isn’t redirection and searching for it as such could yield confusing results. You want a static DNS entry. Unfortunately, it is unlikely that your router supports this.

Comment: Very unlikely that your router supports that with a stock firmware. Instead you could take any linux system and spin up a local DNS server

Answer (score 0):

Check if your modem has a feature named "[DNS Host Mapping](https://www.centurylink.com/home/help/internet/modems-and-routers/advanced-setup/dns-host-mapping.html)", or similar. I've seen that on consumer-grade modems, including old ones.

You'd just enter `mydev` as the host name and `192.168.50.82` as the IP. Then you should be able to access it via the hostname from any device on your network.

One potential problem is that if/when the IP of the server changes, it might not be obvious that you need to login to the router and update the IP of the host entry. You can add a comment in your desktop `/etc/hosts` as a reminder, since you may check it during troubleshooting.